# Trying to scrape a website for frames of videos. Getting 403: Forbidden and 'wrong cookie'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

So I'm trying to scrape a website for frames of videos and getting no luck with a particularly hard-to-get website. I'm new to web scraping, so I could just be missing on something important.

My process for other websites is doing it through youtube-dl and ffmpeg, youtube-dl had support for this website but it is no longer working. I thought on writing a new extractor as I did for other websites but the issue in this website seems different. It's easy to get the .mp4 link for the video but it's hard to get it to work, that is, to display the HTML video player and not a 403: Forbidden or a 'wrong cookie' message.

**I guess I have to mimic a browser request for the link to work, but I'm not sure what I'm missing on. 
This is what I tried so far to identify the problem:**

1. Running `youtube-dl` using the current (not working) implementation for the website. It can successfully get the `.mp4` link, but it's never able to access it.
   Output:

   ```
   59378: Downloading webpage
   WARNING: unable to extract description; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
   ERROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
   ```
2. Using the python requests library. I used sessions to try to keep the cookies from the regular video page to the real URL of the video. It also successfully gets the `.mp4` link, but it's never able to access it. Here is the code:

   ```
   from lxml import html, etree
   import requests

   url = 'LINK GOES HERE'
   header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.12 Safari/537.36'}
   s = requests.Session()
   s.headers.update(header)
   page = s.get(url)
   extractedHtml = html.fromstring(page.content)
   videoUrl = extractedHtml.xpath("//video/@src")
   print("Video URL: ", *videoUrl)
   videoPage = s.get(*videoUrl)
   print(videoPage.content)
   print("Done.")
   ```

   And the output:

   ```
   Video URL: REAL VIDEO (.MP4) URL HERE
   b'Wrong Cookie'
   Done.
   ```
3. Opening the regular video page, then the .mp4 page in Selenium. If I make one get request to the regular page, .mp4 page can work but not reliably as I would ocasionally get 403 or 'wrong cookie' messages. If I make two get requests for the regular page, the .mp4 page will work 100% of the time. So my code is:

   ```
   from lxml import html, etree
   from selenium import webdriver

   url = 'LINK GOES HERE'
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   browser.get(url)
   browser.get(url)
   extractedHtml = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
   videoUrl = extractedHtml.xpath("//video/@src")
   browser.get(*videoUrl)
   print("Done.")
   ```

   Output of this is Selenium opening the .mp4 video page successfully everytime, but I don't know how I could use this to get frames of the video without needing to download the whole thing.

---

Each website is different, so I'm leaving a reference for a video to make everything easier. However the website has NSFW content, so I don't think I can just drop a random link in here. So here is a pastebin with a link to the most SFW video I could find. **Discretion is advised.**

> https://pastebin.com/cBsWg1C7

**If you have any thoughts about this please comment. I'm dreadfully stuck.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open that webpage it shows a disclaimer. Once you click on `Accept`, a cookie is set via their JavaScript code `$.cookie("disclaimer", 1 {` in `jcore.v1.1.229.min.js` (you can find this file attached as a script to the source of the webpage.

Also for a successful connection, you need to send `referer` with the URL of the webpage.

Below is Python code which accepts the disclaimer and downloads the file as `out.mp4`:

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

url = '<webpage-url>'  # change this to the relevant URL

# Get the download link
link_response = requests.get(url)
extracted_html = html.fromstring(link_response.content)
video_link = extracted_html.xpath('//*[@id="videoContainer"]/@data-src')[0]

# Get the video
headers = {'referer': url, 'cookie': 'disclaimer=1'}
video_response = requests.get(video_link, headers=headers)

# Save the video
with open('out.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(video_response.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Didn't thought it would be that simple :)